# How do I control for baseline differences between groups in a multilevel growth curve?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, ancova, growth-model

I am analyzing a repeated measures experiment with 3 groups using a multilevel growth curve in SPSS. I have represented my 3 groups with 2 dummy variables (d1 & d2). I have discovered that there are baseline differences on some of my outcome variables. I have read that to adjust for baseline differences, I should:

1. Include the baseline value of the outcome as a level-2 covariate in the fixed effects portion of the model (and omit the baseline value as an outcome in the repeated measures portion)
   and
2. Re-center time so that the intercept (i.e., time 0) is the first wave of post-intervention data collection (which in my case is Week 1 of the study).

My question is regarding how to properly enter the cross-level interactions between time and my dummy variables (time x d1 and time x d2). Normally, I would enter the two dummy variables as main effects along with the interaction terms (i.e., d1, d2, time x d1, time x d2). With such a setup, I know the main effects for condition (d1 and d2) represent baseline differences between groups when time = 0. However, now that time has been re-centered, I believe the intercept now captures the initial change in scores from baseline to Week 1? Therefore, if I'm not mistaken, the main effects for condition now represent group differences in the change from baseline to Week 1. If that's true, then does including the main effects of condition weaken the time x group interaction terms (because the time x group interaction term will be controlling for any initial group differences in change from baseline to Week 1?)

Essentially, what I'm wondering is if I should still include the main effects of condition when including baseline as a covariate, or should I just include group x time interactions alone without their respective main effects? If I should include the main effects of condition, then how do I interpret the group x time interaction terms given the new intercept?